# Importing an external module in TS causes "ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: typescript

So when importing an external module like so

```
import GameObjects = module("GameObjects")
```

the outputed JS has this at the top of the file:

```
var GameObjects = require("./GameObjects")
```

but gives this error when run in chrome:>  Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

how do I get by this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

External modules require a module loader to be present. If you run this in your browser you have to take care of including a module loader yourself. Please take a look at [require.js](http://requirejs.org), it has all the documentation that's needed to get the module loader running.

Comment: I would have thought Microsoft would have automatically wired that up in the project :(

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the built-in Microsoft solution, then replace your `import` with [Triple Slashes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html).

So instead of `import GameObjects = module("GameObjects")`, you do `/// <reference path="./Gameobjects.ts" />` at the top of the file.